# What open source video editing software packages are available for the Mac?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-editing, open-source

What are open source video editing softwares available for the Mac?
I have used Pitivi, AVS on other systems.

Comment: Does it have to be open source? How about "free as in beer" and "not free, but cheap"?

Comment: "free as in beer" will do? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two:

## [Jahshaka](http://www.jahshaka.com/)

It is an open source free, video editing software, effects, and compositing suite.
[image]
When I used it several months back, it was very unintuitive and I couldn't figure out how to use it. However, there are [tutorials for Jahshaka](http://www.youtube.com/user/FreeWareFrolics) now.

## [Kdenlive](http://www.kdenlive.org/)

Kdenlive is an open source, multi track video editor released under the GNU Public Licence.

[image]
(The screenshot is of Kdenlive running on Windows, but it is available for the Mac through [Macports](http://www.macports.org/))